# How do i stop process running a certain Python script?

Tags: python, linux, ps

I am running two different Python scripts on a Ubuntu VPS. One of them is the production version, and the other one is for testing purposes.

From time to time, I need to kill or restart one of them. However `ps` does not show which script does each Python process runs.

What is the conventional way to do this?

Comment: `ps -x | grep *PROCESS*`

Comment: and then `kill -9 *PROCESS_ID*`

Comment: `pkill -f myscript.py`

Answer (score 2):

`ps -AF` will give you `A`ll processes (not only the ones in your current terminal, or run as your current user), in `F`ull detail, including arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to keep it simple would be to create a screen for each. screen -S prod and screen -S test, then run the python script in the background of each and detach the screen (using ctrl +a+d) then when you need to stop one screen -r prod then kill it/restart then detach again.